# Updating wordpress new version

Tags: wordpress

Getting error while updating wordpress. Need help. I am new in wordpress php. Guide us.

I am trying to update my wordpress installation, but while updating getting error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Close WAMP
Go your the \bin\php\version directory in WAMP
Edit the php.ini, and uncomment the line that reads extension=php_curl.dll
Do the same thing in \bin\Apache\version\bin\
Save and restart WAMP.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happens due to poor internet connection or if connection get interrupted. Try again in another time or connect with a different internet connection.